# Two UIBezierPaths intersection as a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibezierpath

I have two `UIBezierPath`s, one that represents the polygon of part of an image and the other is a path to be drawn on top of it.

I need to find the intersection between them so that only the point that are inside this intersection area will be colored.

Is there a method in `UIBezierPath` that can find intersection points - or a new path - between two paths ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a UIBezierPath library that will let you cut a given closed path into sub shapes based on an intersecting path. It'll do essentially exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/adamwulf/ClippingBezier

```
NSArray<UIBezierPath*>* componentShapes = [shapePath uniqueShapesCreatedFromSlicingWithUnclosedPath:scissorPath];
```

Alternatively, you can also just find the intersection points:

```
NSArray* intersections = [scissorPath findIntersectionsWithClosedPath:shapePath andBeginsInside:nil];
```

Comment: Wow! That looks great!

Comment: Yea, I have integrated it in my Swift code, but there was a compilation error in: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 std::vector"

Comment: Make sure you have `-ObjC -lstdc++` in your Other Linker Flags in your build settings. That should fix that linker error.

Comment: Is this library available in swift?

Comment: The library itself isn't written in swift, but you can still use it in your swift project by adding it to your linked frameworks.

Comment: Just an update that ClippingBezier is now supported by both cocoapods and SPM

Answer (score 10):

I'm not aware of a method for getting a new path that's the intersection of two paths, but you can fill or otherwise draw in the intersection by using the clipping property of each path.

In this example, there are two paths, a square and a circle:

```
let path1 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let path2 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x:50, y:50, width: 100, height: 100))
```

I make a renderer to draw these, but you could be doing this in `drawRect` or wherever:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
let image = renderer.image {
    context in
    // You wouldn't actually stroke the paths, this is just to illustrate where they are
    UIColor.gray.setStroke()
    path1.stroke()
    path2.stroke()
    // You would just do this part
    path1.addClip()
    path2.addClip()
    UIColor.red.setFill()
    context.fill(context.format.bounds)
}
```

The resulting image looks like this (I've stroked each path for clarity as indicated in the code comments, in actual fact you'd only do the fill part):

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to find the union of two or more paths using a similar method?

Comment: UIBezierPath has an `append` method which does this for you

Comment: When doing append, the middle section won't be filled in.

Comment: It is filled, unless you set the `usesEvenOddFillRule` to true

Comment: It still doesn't work, I posted a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168714/uibezierpath-appending-overlapping-isnt-filled) if you would want to take a look at it. Thanks!