# Clipping a CGPathRef or UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cgpath

Given that I have a `CGPathRef`, or a `UIBezierPath`, or some other equivalent iOS representation, are there built in library functions that I can use to compute a clip of this object for me?

- I specifically need to clip against an axis aligned rectangle.
- It'd be very cool to be able to clip against another arbitrary path.
- It'd be even more cool to be able to compute boolean operations on paths: union, difference, intersection (clipping being the intersection operation).

**Note** To clarify, I am *not* asking to be able to *draw* a path with clipping. I want to obtain an actual clipped path, as a new path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my similar answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418390/two-uibezierpaths-intersection-as-a-uibezierpath/42431584?noredirect=1#comment72078045_42431584). I wrote a library that will let you calculate the intersections between any two UIBezierPath and calculate the clipped path between them. The library is at https://github.com/adamwulf/ClippingBezier.

While that other questions deals with the intersection of shapes, you can also simply split two paths into component pieces.

```
NSArray* clippedPathSegments = [UIBezierPath redAndGreenAndBlueSegmentsCreatedFrom:path1 bySlicingWithPath:path2 andNumberOfBlueShellSegments:NULL];
```

That method has a bit of an awkward name, it's used internally for the better named `uniqueShapesCreatedFromSlicingWithUnclosedPath:` method, but should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Adam – your App looks nice and it's great you've shared the algorithms in it. I'm hoping for a non library approach, so I'll leave the question open for a while, but you get an up-vote from me! I imagine that there _isn't_ a built in way, or you wouldn't have built a library :-)

Comment: It's kind of crazy if there's no exposed function for this. `CGContext…` related functions clearly utilise CGPath intersection functionality internally. But I can't see a way to "get that out". I was wondering if I could use `CGContextClip` and then "read out" the clip path, but there doesn't seem to be a way to read it out.

Comment: Completely agree - it's bizarre to me that so little of their bezier code is exposed in the API. Even the UIBezierPath is more limited the already limited NSBezierPath on macOS... if you find a non-library option, definitely let me know, i'll be very curious to see it :)

Comment: It's particularly weird when there _are_ powerful and fairly amazing methods in there such as `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath`, which has the kind of path -> path functionality that is laking for clipping.