# UIBezierPath appending overlapping isn't filled

Tags: swift, uiview, append, uibezierpath

I'm trying to merge two overlapping UIBezierPaths using `UIBezierPath.append`, and I want the overlapping space to be filled. I tried setting the `usesEvenOddFillRule` property to `false`, but it still doesn't fill. Here is minimal example of the problem:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let firstShape = UIBezierPath()

    firstShape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    firstShape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150))
    firstShape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 170))
    firstShape.close()

    let secondShape = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 125, y: 125, width: 75, height: 75))

    let combined = UIBezierPath()
    combined.append(firstShape)
    combined.append(secondShape)

    UIColor.black.setFill()
    combined.fill()
}
```

This yields the following shape:

[image: Shape]

What I would like it to look like:

[image: Wanted shape]

This problem also seems to occur when using `move(to: CGPoint)` on one UIBezierPath. If you would draw both these shapes on the same UIBezierPath, the same problem would occur.

Does anyone know how to make the overlapping region filled? Preferably the solution would also work when doing `addClip()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were on the right track with setting the `usesEvenOddFillRule` to false.  In addition to that, you need to make sure your shapes are both drawn in the same direction (clockwise or counter-clockwise).

I reversed the order of your `addLine`s when drawing the triangle to reverse it.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let firstShape = UIBezierPath()

    firstShape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    firstShape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 170))
    firstShape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150))
    firstShape.close()

    let secondShape = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 125, y: 125, width: 75, height: 75))

    let combined = UIBezierPath()
    combined.append(firstShape)
    combined.append(secondShape)
    combined.usesEvenOddFillRule = false

    UIColor.black.setFill()
    combined.fill()
}
```

Comment: `usesEvenOddFillRule` is false by default. is it required to set it explicitly?

Comment: @Fitsyu, you do not have to set it explicitly if you know it is already set that way.

Comment: You can also use secondShape.reversed() if you see your overlapping space is not filled.

Comment: this didn't work if I apply stroke colors, it is applied for every shape I added

Answer (score 0):

Just call fill before you close the first shape:

```
firstShape.fill()
firstShape.close()
```

Comment: I need to use the merged paths later in the code as a clip, so this unfortunately isn't a solution to the problem